# Use variable inside method's callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Trying to color counties on a google map (with geoJSON). I have a function that is passed the county currently being colored. I then need to use the maps "setStyle" method. My problem is that I can't access the main function variable for the county.

From what I can tell this is an issue with callback functions. I'm clearly not understanding something. Any help is appreciated!

```
function set_color(county){
              map.data.setStyle(function(feature){
                var c_name = feature.getProperty('county');
                var color = "#fafafa";
                if (c_name == county) {
                  color = "red";
                }
                return {
                  fillColor: color,
                  strokeWeight: 1
                }
              })
          }
```

Comment: " I can't access the main function variable for the county." Do you mean you can't access `county` at the `if` block ??

Comment: Yes this is what I mean